# Snoflake use of system$get_tag_on_current_column combined with is_role_in_session does not work?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create or replace masking policy test as (val string) returns string ->
  case when
    system$get_tag_on_current_column('tag_db.tags.a') is null OR is_role_in_session('some_prefix_' || system$get_tag_on_current_column('tag_db.tags.a'))
  then val
  else '**MASKED**' end;
```

fails with:

```
invalid argument for function [IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION] unexpected argument [null] at position 0,
```

Some background:

```
select is_role_in_session('foo' || NULL)
```

returns null, so it seems like get_tag_on_current_column returns NULL..

...but that doesn't make any sense?

So if the above doesn't work, how can I express "evaluate tag value only if the column has assigned the tag"?

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting your OR statement into 2 WHEN statements, with the tag one before the is_role_in_session one.

When the tag is null the first WHEN will be true and therefore the second WHEN statement won't run, so won't error with null values.

Comment: ...when the tag is null the first part of the statement in my example is TRUE, which means that the second part of the statement should not be evaluated. This is exacly the same as you are suggesting